# GraphQL and fetching data directly

Tags: reactjs, graphql, fetch

I am new to web development, and  I was learning GraphQL.
I have a question regarding GraphQL, why do we need GraphQL, can't we just use "fetch" directly to get the data from API? What is the point of using GraphQL? Can someone give me a simple real-life example where GraphQL is used?

Thank you.

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/grapql-from-theory-to-real-world-with-spring-boot-d6b46a28027b check out this link 

And please read the faq section on how to ask good questions in stak overflow

Comment: the link which you have provided didn't answer the question which I asked, pls read my question before commenting. thank you